# Redgate SQL source control: Incorrect repository URL

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, tfs-2015, redgate

I've linked my database (SQServer 2008 R2) to my TFS repository I'm able to commit but unable to pull or push from/to the remote repository via Redgate SQL source control Version 5.4.2.4269

When I attempt to do either I'm asked to enter my credentials in the 'Source control credentials required' dialog box, when I do that it returns an error 'Incorrect details'. I know the issue is not due to my username/password but down to the URL of the repository Redgate believes it should be.

The correct repository URL is http://servername:port/tfs but on the credentials dialog box shows http://servername:port/. If I browse http://servername:port/ I get access denied.

Where does Redgate set the repository URL and can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open SQL Sever Management Studio -SQL source Contro -**Setup**-Next-select TeamFoundationSever-Next Then you will be able to see the repository URL and change the settings.

You could also take a look at this tutorial video [Redgate SQL Source Control - an intro with Steve Jones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz0sH3jL2TM) (Go directly to *3:30*, if you don't want to waste time)

Comment: I was using the GIT link option rather than the TFS option. Thank you.